# Construct String from Binary Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

A bit of a newbie to computing science.

I have the basics for a binary tree in Python:

```py
class TreeBinary:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

This works well on insertion to popularize the tree:

```py
root = TreeBinary(1)
root.left = TreeBinary(2)
root.right = TreeBinary(3)
root.right.right = TreeBinary(4)
```

One of the challenges that I am trying to discover is how to print this tree in order to show the sub-trees if there is one in the following model:

`(1 (2 () ()) (3 () (4 () ())))`
`(2 () ())`
`(3 () (4 () ()))`

I was able to print, but not in this format with these spaces between the sub-trees:

```py
def show_aux(root):
    if not root:
        return ''
    string = str(root.data)
    if root.left or root.right:
        string += '(' + show_aux(root.left) + ')'
    else:
        string += '('
        string += ')'
    if root.right:
        string += '(' + show_aux(root.right) + ')'
    else:
        string += '('
        string += ')'
    return string
def show(root):
    print('(' + show_aux(root) + ')')
```

My results are coming out this way:

`(1(2()())(3()(4()())))`
`(2()())`
`(3()(4()()))`

I would like a direction to print in the expected format with the spaces between the sub-trees.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add spaces before every `(` like this

```
def show_aux(root):
    if not root:
        return ''
    string = str(root.data)
    if root.left or root.right:
        string += ' (' + show_aux(root.left) + ')' #Space before '('
    else:
        string += ' (' #Space before '('
        string += ')'
    if root.right:
        string += ' (' + show_aux(root.right) + ')' #Space before '('
    else:
        string += ' (' #Space before '('
        string += ')'
    return string
def show(root):
    print('(' + show_aux(root) + ')')
```

Comment: Thanks. Seeing now I realize that the solution was right before my eyes.

Comment: Yes . You just needs to improve logic.